# Function evaluation diverges, depending on input precision

Tags: python, precision

I am having problems when evaluating this function:

```
def function(x, B, NP, T, F):
    C= 1/T - 1/(T*F)
    D = 1/T
    return (1/np.cosh(B*x))*np.cos(np.pi*C/B*np.log(np.cosh(B*x)))*np.sin(NP*np.pi*D*x)/np.sin(np.pi*D*x)

time = np.linspace(-2.5e-03, 2.5*1e-03, num = 50000, endpoint = True)

N = 40
b = 2000
f = 3.9
t = 10e-06

result = function(time, b, N, t, f)
```

When I plot the result I get something like this:
[image: result obtained with 50000 points]

Which is expected. However, I would like time_res to be exactly 10ns, so that I will evaluate functions in its zero points. But when I change the number of points in linspace to 500001 this is what I get:
[image: result obtained with 50001 points]

If I zoom in on one of the peaks, this is what I get:
[image: zoom on one of the unexpected features]

which seems clearly a numerical error. That however I can't solve. I have tried to rounding time to 8 decimals, but I obtained a similar "faulty" result, with either 50000 or 50001 points.

Comment: Floating point has roundoff error, which gets compounded

Comment: @Barmar but why only in one of the cases?

Comment: It's like a chaotic system, the precise starting point can have drastic effects.

Comment: Any suggestino on a solution, like a decimal object?